# fedora lvm2 2tb ext4 hdd but physical volume shows 1.1tb used with no more free space

Tags: linux, lvm

Just over half my hard drive is used but lvm shows that there is no more free space to allocate.

How can I investigate further?

- fedora 22, ext4 file system
- 2TB hdd
- used physical space shows as 1.1TiB
- no more free space?

--

```
[root@2012pc home]# df -h  
Filesystem                      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
devtmpfs                        7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /dev  
tmpfs                           7.9G   72M  7.8G   1% /dev/shm  
tmpfs                           7.9G  1.7M  7.9G   1% /run  
tmpfs                           7.9G     0  7.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup  
/dev/mapper/fedora_2012pc-root   50G   16G   31G  34% /  
tmpfs                           7.9G  356K  7.9G   1% /tmp  
/dev/sda2                       477M  142M  306M  32% /boot  
/dev/sda1                       200M  9.4M  191M   5% /boot/efi  
/dev/mapper/fedora_2012pc-var   962G  708G  205G  78% /var  
/dev/mapper/fedora_2012pc-home   96G  3.7G   88G   5% /home  
tmpfs                           1.6G  8.0K  1.6G   1% /run/user/42  
tmpfs                           1.6G   24K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000  
[root@2012pc home]#   
[root@2012pc home]# pvdisplay  
  --- Physical volume ---  
  PV Name               /dev/sda3  
  VG Name               fedora_2012pc  
  PV Size               1.11 TiB / not usable 4.00 MiB  
  Allocatable           yes  
  PE Size               4.00 MiB  
  Total PE              289819  
  Free PE               1  
  Allocated PE          289818  
  PV UUID               0JSehC-3TTF-Mx6B-CG7e-07dq-dNOq-UC2YkD  


[root@2012pc ~]# lsblk  
NAME                   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT  
sda                      8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk   
├─sda1                   8:1    0   200M  0 part /boot/efi  
├─sda2                   8:2    0   500M  0 part /boot  
└─sda3                   8:3    0   1.1T  0 part   
  ├─fedora_2012pc-swap 253:0    0   7.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]  
  ├─fedora_2012pc-root 253:1    0    50G  0 lvm  /  
  ├─fedora_2012pc-home 253:2    0  97.7G  0 lvm  /home  
  └─fedora_2012pc-var  253:3    0 976.6G  0 lvm  /var  
sr0                     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: Are you sure it's a 2T drive, what's the make and model `hdparm -I /dev/sda` should give that information.

Comment: @Iain We can see from the `lsblk` output that it's a 2 TB drive.

Comment: You likely have empty space outside the LVM.

Comment: Thanks for all comments.  Still have not had a chance to get back to this yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last partition is sized to be only 1.1TB, so you have some space on your disk that is not allocated to a partition. You have two choices:

Resize the third partition or create a new partition.

If your disk is partitioned with GPT you may also need to relocate the backup partition table to the end of the disk.

To resize the partition you need to first delete it, and then create it again from the same start sector. If that sounds scary you could use something like `gparted` which can do it safely. Or alternatively simply create a fourth partition in the free space.

Whichever one you choose you then need to reboot.

If you resized the partition next you need to `pvresize /dev/sda3` and you are done.

If you created a new partition you should do this instead:

```
pvcreate /dev/sda4
vgextend fedora_2012pc /dev/sda4
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to resize the /dev/sda3 partition to be bigger, now it's only 1.1 TB instead of the rest of the disk.

Comment: Thanks Janne.  Both answers correct but chutz was more comprehensive.